# Unable to connect to signalr hub on webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

Recently I uploaded (deployed) a signalr hub for a simple chat project(exactly the one that Microsoft uploaded in their signalr website as "getting started project") on a web server. But the problem is I can't connect to hub either from a WinForms application or another chat webapp.
I set the connection url to "http://www.example.com/signalr" but I get a "404 Not found" error when I try to connect via WinForms app. My question is what did I do wrong and do I need to add code to my hub to get it running?

Comment: perhaps sharing some code and the exact error message and where it occurs would help.

Comment: Perhaps it's a Cross-domain issue, does your code makes use of `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` ?

Comment: @Kolichikov Thanks for the reply . its the same sample code that microsoft uploaded in their signalr site [link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Answer (score 1):

i figured out the problem . first i need to edit the url to http://sample.com/signalr without any **www** . after that i didn't get the 404 not found error but i still got error that my signalr version it's not compatible with the server . so i upgraded the signalr client version  and it was done .